# More efficient way with multi-dimensional arrays (matrices) using C++

Tags: c++, matrix, multidimensional-array

I coded a small simple program that compares the performances of several ways to fill a simple 8x8 matrix with different kind of containers. Here's the following code :

```
#define MATRIX_DIM 8
#define OCCUR_MAX 100000

static void genHeapAllocatedMatrix(void)
{
    int **pPixels = new Pixel *[MATRIX_DIM];

    for (type::uint32 idy = 0; idy < MATRIX_DIM; idy++) {
        pPixels[idy] = new Pixel[MATRIX_DIM];
        for (type::uint32 idx = 0; idx < MATRIX_DIM; idx++)
            pPixels[idy][idx] = 42;
    }
}

static void genStackAllocatedMatrix(void)
{
    std::array<std::array<int, 8>, 8> matrix;

    for (type::uint32 idy = 0; idy < MATRIX_DIM; idy++) {
        for (type::uint32 idx = 0; idx < MATRIX_DIM; idx++) {
            matrix[idy][idx] = 42;
        }
    }
}

static void genStackAllocatedMatrixBasic(void)
{
    int matrix[MATRIX_DIM][MATRIX_DIM];

    for (type::uint32 idy = 0; idy < MATRIX_DIM; idy++) {
        for (type::uint32 idx = 0; idx < MATRIX_DIM; idx++) {
            matrix[idy][idx] = 42;
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    clock_t begin, end;
    double time_spent;

    begin = clock();

    for (type::uint32 idx = 0; idx < OCCUR_MAX; idx++)
    {
        //genHeapAllocatedMatrix();
        genStackAllocatedMatrix();
        //genStackAllocatedMatrixBasic();
    }

    end = clock();

    time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    std::cout << "Elapsed time = " << time_spent << std::endl;

    return (0);
}
```

As you can guess the more efficient way is the last one with a simple two-dimentional C array (hard-coded). Of course the worse choice is the number one using heap allocations.
My problem is I want to stock this 2-dimensional array as an attribute in a class. Here's a definition of a custom class that handle a matrix :

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix
{
    public:
        Matrix(void);
        Matrix(type::uint32 column, type::uint32 row);
        Matrix(Matrix const &other);
        virtual ~Matrix(void);

    public:
        Matrix &operator=(Matrix const &other);
        bool operator!=(Matrix const &other);
        bool operator==(Matrix const &other);
        type::uint32 rowCount(void) const;
        type::uint32 columnCount(void) const;
        void printData(void) const;
        T **getData(void) const;
        void setData(T **matrix);

    private:
        type::uint32 m_ColumnCount;
        type::uint32 m_RowCount;
        T **m_pMatrix;
};
```

To do the job done I tried the following thing using a cast :

```
Matrix<int> matrix;
int tab[MATRIX_DIM][MATRIX_DIM];

for (type::uint32 idy = 0; idy < MATRIX_DIM; idy++) {
    for (type::uint32 idx = 0; idx < MATRIX_DIM; idx++) {
        tab[idy][idx] = 42;
    }
}
matrix.setData((int**)&tab[0][0]);
```

This code compiles correctly but if I want to print it there's a segmentation fault.

```
int tab[MATRIX_DIM][MATRIX_DIM];

for (type::uint32 idy = 0; idy < MATRIX_DIM; idy++) {
    for (type::uint32 idx = 0; idx < MATRIX_DIM; idx++) {
        tab[idy][idx] = 42;
    }
}
int **matrix = (int**)&tab[0][0];

std::cout << matrix[0][0] << std::endl; //Segmentation fault
```

Is there a possible way to stock this kind of two dimentional array as an attribute without heap allocation?

Comment: You're measuring the cost of allocation - the fill time will be practically identical in all those cases. Which do you actually care about? And why are you trying to micro-optimise rather than just writing clear, correct code?

Comment: *"As you can guess the more efficient way is the last one with a simple two-dimentional C array (hard-coded)."* Did you compile with optimizations? I get `Elapsed time = 0` for both `std::array` and the C-style array on my *slow* machine.

Comment: Why not have `T m_pMatrix[MATRIX_DIM][MATRIX_DIM]` instead of `T **m_pMatrix`?

Comment: Also, do you absolutely need `T **getData(void) const`? Removing this stuff, if allowed, might simplify your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your responses but I will choose the 'DyP' one. I didn't know the optimizations option in Visual Studio. I chose 'Maximize Speed (/O2)' and for 100000 iterations with std::array container and I also have an elapsed time equal to 0! That's perfect. Thanks so much. Bye.

Answer (score 2):

That's because a two-dimensional array is not an array of pointers.

So, you should use `int *` for your `matrix` type, but then of course you will not be able to index it by two dimensions.

Another option is to store a pointer to the array:

```
int (*matrix)[MATRIX_DIM][MATRIX_DIM];

matrix = &tab;
std::cout << (*matrix)[0][0] << std::endl;
```

But that doesn't suit well an idea of incapsulating matrix in a class. F better idea would be for the class to allocate the storage itself (possibly in a single heap allocation) and to provide an access to the matrix through methods only (e.g. `GetCell(row, col)` etc.), without exposing raw pointers.

Comment: Note, that this is C++, so a reference to array is also an option.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, it would look simpler with a reference.

Answer (score 1):

Measuring the speed of operations on an 8 x 8 array is largely pointless.  For a data set as small as that, the cost of the operation will be close to zero and you are mostly measuring setup time, etc.

Timings become important for larger data sets, but you cannot sensibly extrapolate the small set results to the larger set.  With larger data sets you will often find that the data exists on multiple memory pages.  There is a danger that paging costs will dominate other costs.  Very large improvements in efficiency are possible by ensuring that your algorithm processes all (or most) of the data on one page before moving to the next page, rather than constantly swapping pages.

In general, you are best to use the simplest data structures with the least liklihood of programming error and optimising processing algorithms.  I say "in general" as extreme cases do exist where small differences in access time matter, but they are rare.

Answer (score 0):

Use a single array to represent the matrix instead of allocating for each index.

I've written a class for this already. Feel free to use it:

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T, typename Allocator = std::allocator<T>>
class DimArray
{
    private:
        int Width, Height;
        std::vector<T, Allocator> Data;

    public:
        DimArray(int Width, int Height);
        DimArray(T* Data, int Width, int Height);
        DimArray(T** Data, int Width, int Height);
        virtual ~DimArray() {}

        DimArray(const DimArray &da);
        DimArray(DimArray &&da);

        inline std::size_t size() {return Data.size();}
        inline std::size_t size() const {return Data.size();}

        inline int width() {return Width;}
        inline int width() const {return Width;}

        inline int height() {return Height;}
        inline int height() const {return Height;}

        inline T* operator [](const int Index) {return Data.data() + Height * Index;}
        inline const T* operator [](const int Index) const {return Data.data() + Height * Index;}

        inline DimArray& operator = (DimArray da);
};

template<typename T, typename Allocator>
DimArray<T, Allocator>::DimArray(int Width, int Height) : Width(Width), Height(Height), Data(Width * Height, 0) {}

template<typename T, typename Allocator>
DimArray<T, Allocator>::DimArray(T* Data, int Width, int Height) : Width(Width), Height(Height), Data(Width * Height, 0) {std::copy(&Data[0], &Data[0] + Width * Height, const_cast<T*>(this->Data.data()));}

template<typename T, typename Allocator>
DimArray<T, Allocator>::DimArray(T** Data, int Width, int Height) : Width(Width), Height(Height), Data(Width * Height, 0) {std::copy(Data[0], Data[0] + Width * Height, const_cast<T*>(this->Data.data()));}

template<typename T, typename Allocator>
DimArray<T, Allocator>::DimArray(const DimArray &da) : Width(da.Width), Height(da.Height), Data(da.Data) {}

template<typename T, typename Allocator>
DimArray<T, Allocator>::DimArray(DimArray &&da) : Width(std::move(da.Width)), Height(std::move(da.Height)), Data(std::move(da.Data)) {}

template<typename T, typename Allocator>
DimArray<T, Allocator>& DimArray<T, Allocator>::operator = (DimArray<T, Allocator> da)
{
    this->Width = da.Width;
    this->Height = da.Height;
    this->Data.swap(da.Data);
    return *this;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
int main()
{
    DimArray<int> Matrix(1000, 1000); //creates a 1000 * 1000 matrix.
    Matrix[0][0] = 100;  //ability to index it like a multi-dimensional array.
}
```

**More usage:**

```
template<typename T, std::size_t size>
class uninitialised_stack_allocator : public std::allocator<T>
{
    private:
        alignas(16) T data[size];

    public:
        typedef typename std::allocator<T>::pointer pointer;
        typedef typename std::allocator<T>::size_type size_type;
        typedef typename std::allocator<T>::value_type value_type;

        template<typename U>
        struct rebind {typedef uninitialised_stack_allocator<U, size> other;};

        pointer allocate(size_type n, const void* hint = 0) {return static_cast<pointer>(&data[0]);}
        void deallocate(void* ptr, size_type n) {}
        size_type max_size() const {return size;}
};

int main()
{
    DimArray<int, uninitialised_stack_allocator<int, 1000 * 1000>> Matrix(1000, 1000);
}
```